# Cant get the checkbox to be a boolean using column class

Tags: java, jtable

I have the following code:

The issue i am having is that i want to set the last column as a checkbox boolean, tickable yes or no. However when i set the column class as boolean for the column i still get a string, why is my boolean opt for the column not working?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JButton;

/**
 * TableDemo is just like SimpleTableDemo, except that it uses a custom
 * TableModel.
 */
public class NewClass extends JPanel{
  private boolean DEBUG = false;

  public NewClass() {




    JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));

    //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
    add(scrollPane);

  }

  class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private String[] columnNames = { "First Name", "Last Name", "Sport",
        "# of Years", "Vegetarian" };

    private Object[][] data = {
        { "Mary", "Campione", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5),
            new Boolean(false) },
        { "Alison", "Huml", "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true) },
        { "Kathy", "Walrath", "Knitting", new Integer(2),
            new Boolean(false) },
        { "Sharon", "Zakhour", "Speed reading", new Integer(20),
            new Boolean(true) },
        { "Philip", "Milne", "Pool", new Integer(10),
            new Boolean(false) } };

    public int getColumnCount() {
      return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
      return data.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
      return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
      return data[row][col];
    }


    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
      switch (c){
            case 0:
                return String.class;
            case 1: 
            return String.class;
            case 2: 
                return String.class;
            case 3: 
                return String.class;
            case 4:
               return boolean.class;// i thought here if i define the column data type as boolean i would get checkboxes why not?

            default:
                return String.class;
      }
    }

    /**
     * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's editable.
     */
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
      //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
      //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.

        return false;

    }

    /**
     * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's data can
     * change.
     */
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
      if (DEBUG) {
        System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
            + " to " + value + " (an instance of "
            + value.getClass() + ")");
      }

      data[row][col] = value;
      fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

      if (DEBUG) {
        System.out.println("New value of data:");
        printDebugData();
      }
    }

    private void printDebugData() {
      int numRows = getRowCount();
      int numCols = getColumnCount();

      for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
          System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
      System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }
  }

  /**
   * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
   * invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
   */
  private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Make sure we have nice window decorations.
    NewClass newContentPane = new NewClass();
    JButton button = new JButton("Enter");
    JPanel mainPane = new JPanel();

    mainPane.add(button,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPane.add(newContentPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableDemo");



    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.

    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque


    frame.setContentPane(mainPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.



    //System.out.println(human1.eat());

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });


  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try whit Boolean.class (with à capital B)

Comment: embarrassing! Many thanks

Comment: @ Bastien Aracil if the data in first column is a string, and i set the column class to Integer, what does this mean?

Comment: It means you made a mistake ;-). It might "work" for non editable table but not for editable table. But don't rely on it "works" so I leave it like it.

Comment: Okay many thanks, yes it works for non editable table as i just tested it. I will correctly state the column class with the date type